# Explorer slow with jquery animation. Other browser works well

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer-8

Hi everyone
I have a compatibility problem with a simple jquery plugin i've done for making an animated menu;
You can find the full site here:

[Main site](http://pepito.artkiller-web.com)
[My Library](http://pepito.artkiller-web.com/js/jquery.aa.selOver.js)
[the "bootstrap" file](http://pepito.artkiller-web.com/js/posizionamento.js)

The problem is: the red rectangle animate well throught firefox, opera, chrome...etc.
I've only problem with explorer. It seems that the script works well, but the animation is scattered and very very slow....any idea?

I'm sorry for not having put code sample here, but i definetly don't know where look for the problem.

Thank you guys

Edit: I've found out that the problem was the big image i've temporary put in the page. Now I removed it and everythings works well.
I cannot understand it, but that's all folks :)

Comment: Sidenote: I hope you plan to change the (actual) size of the picture.

Comment: yeah, sure...it's just a testing site, not a production one =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that there's no bug **you** can fix here.

Well, let's face it, IE (lt 9 at least) sucks if it comes to javascript performance. You could [try to optimize your scripts further](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/08/28/728654.aspx), but I wouldn't expect a miracle to happen.

Another option could be to use another PlugIn, with which IE8 might perform better.

Comment: this is not the correct answere, but you hit the problem, it was the big picture slowing down explorer :) now it works fine! so, right answer for u

Comment: @ArtoAle: \*lol\* Wouldn't have thought of that. But I'm glad that you found it.